# Should I encapsulate Task in a Class?

Tags: c#, class, backgroundworker, task, task-parallel-library

I'm building an application having multiple long running worker threads which need to be running 24x7. Each worker is a method in a class called `Bot`. Start/Stop of the `Bot` is controlled by the class itself. So if I need 10 bots running, I just need to instantiate 10 `Bot`, store in a `List<Bot>`, and start everyone of them. I also have a `BotManager` class to manage all the currently running `Bot`

Now, I wanted to use `Task` instead of `Thread` for each of the workers, as they're only spending less than 5% of the time doing any processing.

Should I keep a `Task` in each class or should I inherit my `Bot` from `Task`?

Comment: Since there's only 5% processing time, it should be better with Task. I'm also looking at running at least 100 threads, which is not advisable I believe

Comment: Using Task won't magically solve your problem. You'd need to use features like continuations to take advantage of tasks.

Comment: Wouldn't the CLR make use of the 95% waiting time to allow processing of other Tasks?

Comment: Depends on how you write those tasks. If you write them with continuations, then yes. If you just call a blocking function, then no.

Comment: The original thread design was a long running loop, with `Sleep` and some network IO followed by processing code. How would continuations fit in?

Comment: Tasks run on thread-pool threads. If you explicitly say "suspend this thread for X amount of time" (e.g. `Sleep`), then no, the CLR can't do any other work on that thread -- *you just told it not to!* So Tasks, in your case, will be no better than threads; your tasks are long-running, so you'll have one thread per task. You need to break your tasks down into smaller pieces that run and then finish (so the thread-pool thread is then free to do something else), and use timers instead of sleeps.

Comment: Now I'm seeing the picture. So I need to break say the work in 1 loop into 4 tasks and chain them using continuation. In this case, how should I introduce the delay?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8237149/87399), "the [ParallelExtensionsExtras project](http://geekswithblogs.net/JoshReuben/archive/2010/11/14/parallel-extensions-extras.aspx) contains an extension method for TaskFactory called StartNewDelayed". That might make a decent starting point, though something like ContinueWithDelayed would be better for your needs (and they may have that too).

Comment: After all this, I'm changing my mind to use just 1 tread on the `BotManager`, and fire the first tasks of each loop for all the `Bot`, then use continuations to proceed with the remaining 3 tasks of each `Bot`. Should I rephrase 'this' question?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't descend from `Task`. You're not really extending the idea of "task" and making something that, to code that uses it, is a task with extra features; instead you're just making something that happens to use tasks for its implementation.

I'm also not sure `Task` is a good fit here. If the idea is that these keep running in the background, then that's not playing to TPL's strengths. The best time to use `Task` is when you need composability -- a well-defined task that runs, completes, and then notifies other tasks that it's done and they can start working on its results.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, your requirement is to run as many thread as possible to optimize the CPU usages. And the same time you want framework to take care of this responsibility to increase and decrease the current running threads according to CPU usage.

I would say TPL (Tasks) would the better option. Please look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

We can help you more if you share the nature of your work you want to perform in parallel. What do you exactly mean by 24X7 running tasks? What kind of work your tasks perform? Is it computing or IO (DB operation/Web Service Call)?

I am assuming that each request consists of 4 steps and these steps are executed in following sequence,
1. DB Look-up 
2. Web service call 
3. DB Update 
4. Log to File

As you mentioned Web service call takes time and therefore best suited for asynchronous I/O task.

Next you said,

> CPU intensive part will be the db lookup

But I understand that db lookup does not use CPU and it is an I/O activity and again good candidate for asynchronous I/O task.

Considering all these assumptions I suggest following,

1. DB Look-up (Run asynchronously so that thread pool thread will be freed to process other requests)
2. Web service call (Run asynchronously so that thread pool thread will be freed to process other requests)
3. DB Update (Run synchronously)
4. Log to File (use asynchronous logging depending upon log content size)

According to my understanding none of your steps are CPU intensive that is why you are seeing only 5% of CPU usages.

You also mentioned,

> followed by a random delay to distribute the load evenly.

Did you mean to run as much as possible such requests (consists of these 4 steps)? If so then you do not need to put any extra stuff. Because when a request waits for asynchronous call then it frees the thread pool thread and system can use it to process other request. This will increase the throughput.

> Should I keep a Task in each class or should I inherit my Bot from
>   Task?

1 Bot represent to 1 request. Tasks represent to Steps within a request. So create tasks within your BOT class.

Run it with different number of requests and verify the usages of CPU, Memory and other system resources.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The 4 task that's perform in the loop is db look up, web service call, db update, log to file, followed by a random delay to distribute the load evenly. The most time consuming would be the web service call. CPU intensive part will be the db lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the delay explanation. The random delay is some what required, because we're accessing multiple server for the Web Service call, but not to overload the server unnecessarily.

Comment: Is that means, single request calls multiple web services and then wait to collate their results. I could not see any other scenarios for explicit delay.

Comment: No really, each bot will be assigned to one web service destination. The number of bot will equal the number of web service we have. We don't need to access all web service continuously. And also we have limited bandwidth on our end to connect to all the web services. So a random delay will hopefully spread out the request.

Comment: Hi Faulty! Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a "task" for tasks. Use threads. When you need assurance, that your code is actually running (and on a fixed amount of threads) you **cannot use tasks**. Tasks do not guarantee parallel execution. You must allocate threads yourself. If you want to save resources reduce the threads stack size using the constructor.

Comment: I do not need guaranteed parallel execution. All I need is to optimize the CPU and be able to run as much `Bot` as possible

Comment: Would you be comfortable with only 4 bots running at the same time and the other 6 bots never running? As I understood you, your bots essentially run forever. They run 24x7. So their tasks never exit and the threads these tasks run on are never made available again.

Comment: I see, I thought it would switch to other task when I call Thread.Sleep

Comment: That is not guaranteed, and it will not always happen in practice. Use Threads for long-running work or for work that needs to run in all cases.